# Importing a private key from a string using Crypto++

Tags: c++, cryptography, crypto++

So first I create a signing object like so:

```
CryptoPP::ECDSA<CryptoPP::ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256>::Signer signer;
```

I generate them like so:

```
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng; //Create a random number
signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1());
```

I also validate the generated keys to check everything is fine:

```
signer.AccessKey().Validate(prng, 3))
```

These are then exported to a string:

```
std::string key;
CryptoPP::StringSink pss(key);
signer.AccessKey().Save(pss);
```

However when it comes to loading these keys back up:

```
CryptoPP::StringSink ss(key);
signer.AccessKey().Load(ss);
```

I receive and exception:

```
BER decode error
```

Just to note the signing object is blank upon attempting to load could this be it?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I believe it's the method for loading the key back into the Access key and I should be importing the key to the StringSink differently but I'm not sure. Please could I have some help trying to load my keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:

> ```
> std::string p_key;
> CryptoPP::StringSink pss(p_key);
> signer.AccessKey().Save(pss);
> ```

This looks like the problem assuming `p_key` and `key` are the same:

> ```
> CryptoPP::StringSink ss(key);
> signer.AccessKey().Load(ss);
> ```

Use as `StringSource` when loading, not a `StringSink`:

```
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(key);
signer.AccessKey().Load(ss);
```

All sources and sinks are interchangeable. You can use a `FileSource` instead of a `StringSource`; and a `FileSink` instead of a `StringSink`. But you can't replace a source with a sink (or vice versa).

`StringSource` and `StringSink` are part of pipelines in Crypto++. [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) and [Keys and Formats](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats) from the Crypto++ wiki may be useful for you. But the code you showed is clean (other than the typo) so you may not need them.

Comment: I think it should be `CryptoPP::StringSource ss(key, true);` as you get an error else. Thank you so much though!